# RMI Classloading causing almost 2 minutes of wait

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, rmi, distributed-computing

I'm having an issue with RMI. The situation is like this:
I have a JBOSS 4.2.2 Server that expose an EJB Object, there is a client in a different server, running tomcat, that uses RMI to invoke the EJB on JBoss. When JBoss throws an exception and propagates it to the client side, there is a problem because part of the exception is not in the classpath of tomcat, so an RMI exception happens. We noticed that RMI tries to load the class from the server, but we don't have setted the codebase parameter, so it fails.

The problem is that the response could take something like 2 minutes. If we start tomcat with the property "useCodeBaseOnly=true", the response happens immediately, the same happens if we put the missing class on tomcat.
If I test the situation locally (jboss+tomcat on the same machine) the response doesn't take too much time.  Is there something like a Timeout to the UrlClassLoader to return if the class is not available?, what could cause the slowness on the response?.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just fix the underlying issue and cook those exceptions into something that adheres to best practices? You shouldn't let any which exception, together with its whole cause chain, escape to the client.

Comment: I know, that would fix my problem. But I really want to understand what is causing that huge lag on the system. Thx.